# Bug in ipad safari blank space

Tags: jquery, html, safari, fullpage.js

I have a certain bug when surfing to my website:
http://eurocom.richkid.co.il/en in ipad safari.
when first surfing into the site its all well
when open new tab in safari the view size is changed because the tabs has height.
so when open new tab and back to the old tab (my website)
there is a white space at the end because it is not causing resize. and in each resize i am giving minimum height to each section. so actually how can i solve this?
bug image:
http://jpg.co.il/view/55e566d160d47.png/

code for minimum height:

```
SetHeight();
function SetHeight()
{
    var height=getBrowserHeight().height;
    $(".mainSection").css("min-height",height+"px");
}
$( window ).resize(function() {
  SetHeight();
});

    function getBrowserHeight() {
        var intH = 0;
        var intW = 0;

        if (typeof window.innerWidth == 'number') {
            intH = window.innerHeight;
            intW = window.innerWidth;
        }
        else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            intH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            intW = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        }
        else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
            intH = document.body.clientHeight;
            intW = document.body.clientWidth;
        }

        return { width: parseInt(intW), height: parseInt(intH) };
    }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Related with [this bug in fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1442) caused by solving a Chrome 44 bug.

Solutions for now?

Use the fullpage.js option `css:false` or what I would recommend: `scrollBar:true`.

Hopefully Chrome will fix its bug soon and you won't have to worry about it.